# Oracle sql date timestamp filter

Tags: oracle

My Oracle table has 1,000 observations the following 2 variables: (Both fields are varchar)

```
ID   datecreate
ABC  24/12/2016 05:32:07
```

I would like to filter the dates. I tried the following but to no avail...

```
select *
from table
where datecreate >= to_date('01/02/2018 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and
datecreate <= to_date('28/02/2018 23:59:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

I keep getting the following error...

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Did I miss something obvious?

Thanks

Comment: Step 1: Stop storing dates as VARCHAR2's.

Comment: if you search for 'ORA-01843' on this site you get a large list of posts. And none of them did help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been emphasized several times that in databases, `DATE` and `TIME` should not be stored as strings. Yet, there are several questions raised everyday, arising solely due to this poor practice.

Note that in Oracle, datetimes can either be stored as `DATE` type or `TIMESTAMP`( with or without `TIMEZONE` ). The `DATE` type contains the time component as well.

`TO_DATE` function comes to our rescue in cases where date strings have to be dealt with for conversion. While using dates, it is a good practice to use standard `DATE` literals in `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format which most DBMSes understand.  ( eg:- `DATE '2018-02-28'` ).

Also, you need not use `'28/02/2018 23:59:00'` or `TRUNC` function for such boundary cases, when you can use `DATE` literals. So, your query could be rewritten as

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  TO_DATE(datecreate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') >= DATE '2018-02-01'
   AND TO_DATE(datecreate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  < DATE '2018-02-28' + 1
```

or `< DATE '2020-02-29'` if you know that it's a leap year.

If you really want to consider till `23:59` minutes, then `TIMESTAMP` literals could be used with `TO_TIMESTAMP` function.

```
.. AND  TO_TIMESTAMP(datecreate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') <
        TIMESTAMP '2018-02-28 23:59:00'
```

Comment: Great explanations Kaushik. Unfortunately there are many poor database practices in storing data and as coder, we have to twist our logic to cater for this......

Answer (score 2):

The default NLS_DATE_FORMAT currently is DD-MON-RR. Thus your datecreate column defined as string will be implicitly converts to that format. The value 12  is not the same as DEC, thus the error. Either you use the right format or convert it to date similar below.

```
select *
from tbl
where to_date(datecreate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') >= 
to_date('01/02/2016 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
and to_date(datecreate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') <= 
to_date('28/02/2018 23:59:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: "The default date format in Oracle is DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'" - That is not true. `Date` does not have any format by itself. However, the output depends on the user's local NLS settings defined initially by default  or the  `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter.

Comment: corrected it. thanks.